# Laravel custom package not loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a package in the following path: ***packages/mypackage/demo***

and my service provider is in:

```
packages/mypackage/demo/src/vis/MyserviceProvider.php
```

and I have added in `composer.json` as:

```
"psr-4": {
      "Custom\\MyPackage\\": "packages/mypackage/demo/src/vis/",

        "App\\": "app/"
    }
```

Ran `composer update` and ran `composer dump-autoload -o`

and added service provider in `app.php`:

`Custom\MyPackage\MyserviceProvider::class,`

but I get the following error:

> MyserviceProvider not found

Can anyone help me how I can fix this issue?

Comment: You need to have a `composer.json` configured in your package directory too. Do you have one there?

Comment: @BenjaminDowson.yes i ahve

Answer (score 0):

The path of the package in your folder is something like this *packages/mypackage/demo/src*

With every Laravel application there is a main `composer.json` file in the root of every new app. This is your main application composer file and this is where we define all our app dependencies.

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Mypackage\\Demo\\": "packages/mypackage/demo/src"
    }
},
```

Then we need composer to run the autoloader and autoload our package. To do this we run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

**Add our package service provider.**

The service provider is the main entry inside of our package. This is where our package is loaded or booted. In the root of our app, let's create our ServiceProvider with an artisan command via the command line:

```
php artisan make:provider MyServiceProvider
```

This will create a new file located at app/Providers/MyServiceProvider.php

Let's move this file into our package folder so that way it lives at `packages/mypackage/demo/src/MyServiceProvider.php`

**NOTE:** Don't forget to change your *namespace* to be your Vendor\Package_name in  MyServiceProvider.php file **Example:**

```
<?php
namespace Mypackage\Demo;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class MyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{    }
```

Next, we need to add our new Service Provider in our `config/app.php` inside of the `providers[]` 
array:

```
'providers' => [

    /*
     * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
     */
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthServiceProvider::class,
    //.. Other providers
    Mypackage\Demo\MyServiceProvider.php::class,

],
```

Now, Our service provider is loaded and our custom package is ready to use.

Comment: This explains how to load the package code using the root project's composer.json. It will not work if the package is installed into another project.